# Computer monitor automatically wakes up without a timer when I am in proximity

Tags: display, timeout

Don't know if this is on topic, and Google searching isn't helpful.

I have a weird thing to report, this is 100% real, without exaggeration, and I want to know is there any way to scientifically explain this phenomenon.

This problem has puzzled me for months, it is really simple. My computer's monitor has a timemout of 10 minutes, meaning after 10 minutes of inactivity, the screen turns black. My computer's operating system is Windows 10, the OS is set to turn off the screen after 15 minutes, and I have set it to never sleep.

Now here is the weird thing, if I leave the computer for long enough, the screen automatically shuts down, this isn't weird in itself, but if the monitor is turned off in this fashion, due to inactivity, instead of by physical power button press, if I move the mouse or press a key on the keyboard, while the screen is off and the computer is on...

The monitor turns itself on, but only sometimes. This may be unusual, but it seems explainable. This happens infrequently, and it only happens if the monitor is turned off due to inactivity timeout, instead of being manually turned off via power button.

The above may be strange, but it is nothing compared to what I am going to tell you next. If I leave the computer for long enough, and the monitor is powered off due to inactivity, when I return to the computer, when I enter the room where the computer is kept and get within about 0.5 meter radius of the monitor...

The monitor turns itself on automatically without needing the mouse or keyboard to be touched, at all. Just my very presence is enough to wake up the monitor, seemingly magically. The monitor seems to greet me, this happens extremely rarely, but it has happened about a dozen times or so in the past 6 months.

There isn't a timer that is set to turn my monitor automatically on after some fixed period of time. The monitor can wake up in this fashion if I returned after one hour and some or two hours and some or twelve hours and some, the duration of inactivity seems irrelevant.

My computer is connected to the Ethernet, obviously, but most of the time my computer is the only device connected to the LAN from my router, and I use mobile data on my phone because it is easier for my phone to circumvent the GFW with mobile data than with network provided by my optical fiber ISP.

My computer doesn't have any sensors that could sense my presence, there isn't a webcam or a microphone, my computer setup includes a monitor, a mouse, a keyboard, a set of speakers, and a computer case. Inside the case is the motherboard, the motherboard has a CPU and a dedicated GPU on it, two RAM sticks, and a fan for the CPU. Besides the motherboard and things on it, there are two HDD's and an SSD, all connected via SATA cables. And finally there is a PSU inside the case, which has its own fan.

The above plus some wires used to connect the components, are everything in my setup, there are no components that can conceivably turn the monitor on when I am near, and yet it is exactly what happens, the monitor will rarely turn itself on when I am in proximity. This happened again to me today, but as I said because it happens very rarely I wasn't expecting it and therefore I didn't record it. I don't know how to reproduce it, but I will try to record it when it happens next time to use as proof.

Is there any way to scientifically explain this?

---

Reply to the comments:

The floor of my room is hard stone, my computer setup is on a desk made of wood that is fixed in place, it is immovable.

I will show you:

[image]

Comment: *My computer doesn't have any sensors that could sense my presence...a mouse...* Are you absolutely sure that the floor does not bend under your weight and that the mouse does not slide a fraction of a millimeter when you approach? Just believe me, electronics is a dark and confusing thing, but there are no miracles in it

Comment: OK. I thought I was going nuts. The same thing has happened to me numerous times. My hypothesis is that it is somehow due to static electricity... but the *somehow* is a mystery.

Comment: @EndAnti-SemiticHate Well. Does the computer react the same way to other people? Try sneaking around on tiptoes. Cover the webcam lens. Avoid wearing synthetic and wool items. I had an employee who simply walking up to the printer caused it to stop printing. She was just curvy. It turned out that the signal cable was damaged, but the weight of the other employees was not enough to cause a short circuit.

Comment: Reminds me of [Mr. Bean](https://youtu.be/bl3Fd4WlCqI?si=Pl8-iLmiz3cbuUc8&t=388). You might want to check how the monitor reacts to your underwear!

Comment: Turn the mouse on its back before you walk away. Mine used to wake the computer if I walked past the desk. That was my 'fix'. My OS now only responds to key-presses, not mouse movement, so that particular issue has now disappeared.

Comment: The mouse is the most likely sensor. One other faint possibility: a cell phone in your pocket. Cell phones send out periodic signals to check if there is a tower nearby, and these are often picked of as a *beep beep* on wired speakers. It *could* be your mobi signalling is picked up on a wire... or not.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a gaming mouse check the sensitivity some of the high end mice can have extreme sensitivity with a DPI of 16,000 how much does the mouse have to move?

However its also possible your monitor has a capacitive sensor similar to the screens in phones/iPads. I have a very old (> 10 year) Dell monitor that has a capacitive sensor on one of the buttons - whenever I move my finger within about 1 inch of the button the button lights up. I have verified that it is a capacitive sensor, I can wave white paper in front of it and nothing - but if I move a black metal object in the same location it lights up.

In either of these cases it's probably not your immediate presence that's causing the issue. When you enter the room there will be a small amount of movement conveyed through the floor.

If either the mouse is sensitive enough or there is something metal near the capacitive sensor that tiny bit of movement could be enough to trigger this.